# Check Duplicates

Tags: asp.net, duplicates, dataview

I'm using following code which is not working to check duplicate values for "Revision Status"

```
private bool CheckRevision(string docType,string Revision)
        {
            bool Res = false;
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            DT = PinDicDAO.GetRevision(docType);
            DataView DV = new DataView(DT);
            DV.RowFilter = "RevisionStatus='" + Revision.Replace(" ", "") + "' OR RevisionStatus='"+Revision+"'";
            if (DV.Count > 0)
                Res = true;

            return Res;
        }
```

format of the RevisionStatus will be like

```
CN - Cancelled
IFP - Issued For Purchase
```

Comment: What is your base datasource?  A database?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the datatable instead.

```
if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
                Res = true;

            return Res;
```